# Why Typescript can't use includes function for array?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I know that Typescript use ES6 or ES2015.

And I know that `anArray.includes('ifExist');` only available in ES6.

But why can't I use it when I use Typescript?
It says that `anArray` don't have a method `includes`.

**My Array**

```
anArray = [
    {
        'category': 'x',
        'data': []
    }, 
    {
        'category': 'y',
        'data': []
    }, 
    {
        'category': 'z',
        'data': []
    }
];
```

**ifExist variable**

```
ifExist = {
    'category': 'a',
    'data': []
};
```

If I use `anArray.indexOf(isExist) < 0`, I can get the result like `anArray.includes(isExist)`.

Comment: Your `anArray` is probably not typed as an array. You need to provide code that reproduces the problem

Comment: I've edited my question for more explanation :d

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Specifications) it's in ES2016.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify `target` in your `ts-config.json` to `ES2016` (or higher) in order to use `Array.includes`.

Comment: I see, it's my mistake too, `includes` method is in ES2016, not ES2015. And I use ES2015. I thought `includes` is in ES2015. Then this answer will definitely solve my problem. Thank you. :)

Comment: Is there a place where this information is kept? I was thinking maybe [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) would tell me which version of EcmaScript this was introduced but it doesn't seem to 

Comment: @AhmedFasih I mainly use https://node.green to check this, although its purpose is to list which ecmascript features are available in which node version.

Comment: Oh interesting! Yes I see it under "Node.js ES2016 Support"! Thank you!! I was grepping for another function in this directory: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/main/src/lib  this is much better